# How can I make bash arrays behave while I iterate through them?

Tags: for-loop

I've got an array with a number of strings in them and want to do some work on each string.  I'd have thought a simple for loop would work but this is causing serious problems:

```
for list in $valarr
do

    for word in ${valarr[j]}
    do
    #echo word: $word
    if [ $i -ge $f ] && [ $i -le $t ]; then
        echo -e -n "$word\t"
    fi
    i=`expr $i + 1`
    done
    echo $j ${#valarr[@]}
    i=0
    j=`expr $j + 1`
done
```

As you can see I've got two loops.  The one nested inside does the work I need done (and works fine) but the outer for-loop thinks that the number of elements it has is *the number of words in its first element (string)*.  Structurally all I really want to do is something like this:

```
for each string in an array:
    for each word in the string:
        do some work
    done
done
```

Why does bash behave like this and how can I accomplish what I need to do?  (Apologies, btw, for any problems in clarity or formatting)

Answer (score 1):

You loop through an array like this:

```
for var in "${valarr[@]}"
```

The [@] is important;  bare `$arrayName` is the same as `${arrayName[0]}`.  Which is why your loop is looping through the words in your first element.